# How to correct do tagging of the tables?

Tags: tables, errors, luatex, environments, expl3

Please,help me,how i can correct do tagging of the tables. I try to do it,but i get an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
```

I guessed,what this error happens because to the \tabular command i give nothing as argument. I tryed give one,two,three and four arguments,but this error is not disappear. Using \message command i noticed,what each argument,which i give to command,using \cs_gset_protected:cpn{tabular}#1 #2 #3 #4{\some_code} gives to command tabular for each argument only one character. for example for \tabular{ccc} i have things like { c c c for each argument. Help me please fix this error. Also help me please,what command should i use for table,tabbing and any other table environment,for each line and cell. I will do tagging of this environments myself,if i will know this commands. Thank you very much for your help with fixing of error and with commands for table environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@tabular}{tabular}
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@endtabular}{endtabular}
\cs_gset_protected:cpn{tabular}{
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l__tab_char: {
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
    \c_alignment_token
}
\char_set_active_eq:NN \& \l__tab_char:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \&
\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}
\use:c{orig@tabular}
\let\orig@startfield=\@startfield
\let\orig@stopfield=\@stopfield
\let\orig@startline=\@startline
\let\orig@stopline=\@stopline
\renewcommand{\@startfield}{
\tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
\orig@startfield
}
\renewcommand{\@stopfield}{
\orig@stopfield
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
}
\renewcommand{\@startline}{
\tagstructbegin{tag=TR}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
\orig@startline
}
\renewcommand{\@stopline}{
\orig@stopline
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
}
}
\cs_gset_protected:cpn{endtabular}{
\use:c{orig@endtabular}
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a&b
c&d
\end{tabular}
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't clear why you are using `\use:c` here. `\use:c{orig@tabular}\let` is just an inefficient equivalent to `\orig@tabular\let` so the argument to tabular is `\let` not `{ccc}` hence the error. You need `\orig@tabular` to be the very last thing in the redefinition, so it picks up the argument from the document.

Comment: also you have redefinitions of startline stopline etc inside your tabular redefinition, but they are unrelated to `tabular` and are internal commands for the `tabbing` environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear the intention here but the error is because you were calling `\orig@tabular` in the middle of the definition so its argument is the following token (`\let`) not the `{cc}` from the document.

In this case all the following tokens are redefinitions of internal commands from `tabbing` not relevant to `tabular` so I simply deleted them, it runs but with some warnings about the tag structure.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\cs_set_eq:NN\orig@tabular\tabular
\cs_set_eq:NN\orig@endtabular\endtabular
\cs_gset_protected:Npn\tabular{
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l__tab_char: {
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
    \c_alignment_token
}
\char_set_active_eq:NN \& \l__tab_char:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \&
\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}
\orig@tabular
}
\cs_gset_protected:Npn\endtabular{
\orig@endtabular
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tabular}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{tabular}
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

warns

```
tagpdf: WARN! MC1 has no kids
tagpdf: WARN! MC1 has no kids
tagpdf: WARN! MC2 has no kids
tagpdf: WARN! MC2 has no kids
```

Comment: I want to do tagging of all table: each line of table and each cell for the table,so i need in redefining of \@startline and \@stopline with \@startfield and \@stopfield inside a table environments,but i have some problems with arguments of this commands. In fact inside my package i did property,which contains table,tabular,tabin,etc,so i redefine commands for all of this environments. Also i have a question: Why instead of c you used N? Thank you very much for your help. Also help me please,what commands should i use for tagging of each cell and line of tabular.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy Redefining `\@startline` and `\@stopline` will have no effect as those commands are completely unrelated to the `table` and `tabular` environments. You may need to redefine them for `tabbing` but such a definition should not be local to a redefinition of `tabular` that can not work at all.  Using N is vastly more efficient than c in time and space: `c` allows a name to be constructed but it is a constant here. `\use:c{tabular}` is 10 tokens and expands in two steps to `\tabular`. compared to `\tabular` which is one token and is `\tabular` with no expansion needed.

Comment: Ok,so for table and tabular i can use \@start/stopline commands and &? Should i redefine \start/stopfield commands locally for tabbing environment. In what cases using c mor efficient than N?

Comment: Why for use:c{tabular} i have 10 tokens,because it seems we have 9 tokens: { t a b u l a r },or \,which not use in this variant,is token to?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy you could use commands `\@startline` but it would be very confusing, why use names from `tabbing` in a redefined `tabular`?  `c` is never more efficient. `\csname abc\endcsname` expands to `\abc` so will always take an extra expansion step.

Comment: you have not counted the `\use:c` token in the 10

Comment: Ok,but what commands i can redefine for each line/cell of table/tabular?

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy the site really doesn't work having extended discussion in comments. There are _no_ commands that correspond to tabular rows or cells, so you can not redefine an existing macro you need to somehow redefine the tabular definition itself to insert the needed tagging.

Comment: Ok,nay be exists way at least redefine start and/or end of line on the table? Also it seems,that \table command have several arguments,but for now i redefine it as command without any argument. What do you think about it? About descussions,nay be you right,but how can i find site or some group for discussion like this?

Comment: May be i can someone redefine \\ command for table/tabular? If true,can you please help me,how to do this correct,because it can be probably problem with catcodes.

Comment: when i use this code with \maketitle,the error not disappear. Yes,without arguments,probably,it will works,but \tabular command have at least one mandatory argument and one optional,so i redefine it with one argument. But i have a problems with this (please look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569449/not-works-tagging-of-tabular-with-one-cell) Thanks very much for your help.