# not works tagging of tabular with one cell

Tags: errors, luatex, environments, compiling, expl3

I desided create a new question for this,because this question connected with previous question. I decided use properties,for tagging of several environments. But for \maketitle,in which use \tabular,i get an error:

! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

Please help me to solve this problem (now it's not important,what pdf we have,because in our package we have more code for this: I simple decrease code,to
show my problem). Thanks everybody for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn{\g__tables_prop}{table=0,endtable=1,table*=0,endtable*=1,tabular=0,endtabular=1,tabular*=0,endtabular*=1,tabbing=0,endtabbing=1,tabbing*=0,endtabbing*=1}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \g__tables_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc{orig@#1}{#1}
\cs_gset_protected:cpn{#1}##1{
\int_case:nnF{#2}
{
{0} %somethin with \begin,e.g \begin{tabular}
{
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l__tab_char: {
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
    \c_alignment_token
}
\char_set_active_eq:NN \& \l__tab_char:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \&
\tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
\tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}
\use:c{orig@#1}{##1}
\message{argument~##1}
}
{1} %somethin with \end,e.g \end{tabular}
{
\use:c{orig@#1}{##1}
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
}
}
{}
}
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\maketitle{} %error
\makeatletter
%this code works ok.
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1&2&3
\end{tabular}
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\end{tabular}` has no argument, so redefining it to take one is bound to explode. And `\begin{tabular}` can take an optional argument (which is eg used in `\maketitle`: `\begin{tabular}[t]{c}` and you are not handling that at all.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Ok,i changed code to handle this,but error nod disappear. Please,look at https://pastebin.com/PimW1Rn6. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `\cs_gset_protected:cpn{#1}##1 ##2{` doesn't work. tabular doesn't have two arguments, it has one mandatory argument and one optional one.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Ok,how i can fix this for \tabular command?

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Please,help me to solve this problem. How to use commands with optional arguments in expl3?

Comment: optional arguments for commands are document level features, if you want to handle them in expl3 you will have to use the peek-commands to check future tokens and split the code. It is easier if you use \renewcommand or \RenewDocumentCommand. But be aware that tabulars are complicated.  I wouldn't dare to do your redefinitions without lots of tests with array, colortbl and other packages using or changing tabular.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Ok,can you please help me,how i can fix it for \maketitle command,that i can understand,how to work with commands with optional arguments in expl3 or give me please link on example,how work with this commands using expl3. What differents between \newcommand and \NewDocumentCommand?

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Also i noticed,what in \maketitle for \tabular arguments divides on several tokens and each argument it one character. Without \maketitle all works ok. I found an example for optional commands without expl3,but i want to do it in expl3,because in future,as i understood,latex2 format will disappear.

Comment: No the latex2e format will not disappear. The plan is to develop it. See e.g. Frank Talk at tug 2020: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNci4lcb8Vo

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Thank you very much for this video. Can you please write example for solving the problem atleast with maketitle,that i understood idea,how to solve similar problems or may be you have an example for redefining of some commands,which show an example,how to solve it,and i will fix my example myself? What differents between \renewcommand and \RenewDocumentCommand?

Comment: How i can redefine commands with option arguments using expl3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is probably `\pretocmd` from `etoolbox` package. Also, your LaTeX coding and indentation are a bit sloppy. If you may find it helpful, I have written a [tutorial](https://www.alanshawn.com/tech/2020/10/04/latex3-tutorial.html) on LaTeX3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,
  uncompress,
  activate-all,
  add-new-tag=Title/P,
  interwordspace=true
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_tab_env_clist

\clist_gset:Nn \g_tab_env_clist {
  table,
  table*,
  tabular,
  tabular*,
  %tabbing,
  %tabbing*
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \pre_to_cmd:Nnnn \pretocmd
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \pre_to_cmd:Nnnn {cnnn}

\clist_map_inline:Nn \g_tab_env_clist {
  \pre_to_cmd:cnnn {#1} {
    \char_set_active_eq:NN \& \g__tab_char:
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \&
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Table}
    \tagstructbegin{tag=TBody}
  }{}{
    \GenericError {}{unable~to~patch~command~"#1"}{}{}
  }
  
  \pre_to_cmd:cnnn {end#1} {
    \tagstructend
    \tagstructend
  }{}{
    \GenericError {}{unable~to~patch~command~"end#1"}{}{}
  }
}


\cs_set_protected:Npn \g__tab_char: {
  \tagmcend
  \tagstructend
  \tagstructend
  \tagstructbegin{tag=TD}
  \tagstructbegin{tag=P}
  \tagmcbegin{tag=P}
  \c_alignment_token
}


\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test}

\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}

\maketitle{}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1&2&3
\end{tabular}

\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: I do find it a bit hilarious to disguise  \pretocmd as expl3  like this. Besides I would use the new environment hooks instead (and they have genuine expl3 interfaces).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am really clumsy when it comes to `\expandafter`, `\csname` etc. Therefore, I create `\pre_to_cmd:cnnn` so that I can pass the first argument to `\pretocmd` as `c` type.

Comment: you could simply use \exp_args:Nc before the command. And if you want to rename it, consider if `pre` is the right module name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not really for the name lawyering thing though...I think when writing  some informal code, naming should be rather casual. Module name makes naming complicated...For example, variables like `\c_left_brace_str`, `\c_one_degree_fp` are good enough, even without module name.

Comment: `\c_left_brace_str` is not casual, it follows the rule that the module name is not added twice. So it is `\l_tmpa_tl` and not `\l_tl_tmpa_tl`. Beside this: you are writing here not to a restricted, known group, you can't expect all readers here  to understand that you are violating the naming scheme.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Do you consider,what instead of \pre_to_cmd it better use \exp_args to add something before command? If yes,what you recommend use if i want to add something after command?